# SQLServer Profiler unable to connect. Unknown Error Pfutil

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

[image]

This is remote server in my LAN.

- I am able to connect other instances (2016,2017) on this server via
  any SSMS.
- I am able to connect sql2014 instance on the other server, but not on this one.

I have tried:

1. Use any of SSMS Manaement studio 2014,2016,2017(17.9) as Admin
2. `regsvr32 sqlncli11.dll` (with success msg via admin cmd)
3. Restart computer
4. Uninstall (Add&Remove programs) -> Repair Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
5. Run setup.exe for SQL2012 / SQL2014 and use Repair option
6. Uninstall (Add&Remove programs) -> Restart -> Install using setup.exe and add feature to existing instance

Comment: It seems like COM registration issues with SQLNCLI11.DLL. have you executed the "regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\sqlncli11.dll" from an administrative command prompt???

Comment: yes i updated question with few more steps I did without succees